# How to print out api data to discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make a discord command to print a phone number out of a API. The Error I get is:

```
if x["cod"] != "404": 
    KeyError: 'cod'
```

if anyone could help me on how to print the api data would be great

```
@client.command()
async def o(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    url = "https://random-data-api.com/api/phone_number/random_phone_number"
    response = requests.get(url)
    x = response.json()
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    if x["cod"] != "404":
        async with channel.typing():
            y = x["id"]
        cell_phone = y["phone"]
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Het weer in {cell_phone}",
        color=0x00FFFF,
        timestamp=ctx.message.created_at,)
    return await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: File "main.py", line 312, in o
    if x["cod"] != "404":
KeyError: 'cod'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason your getting `KeyError: 'cod'` is because it can't find "cod" in the api url.

What your checking also is that if "cod" does not equal to string 404 then send the embed, but what I think your trying to check is if the api status code is 404 which you can use `x.status_code` to check that.

This would be the correct code to get phone number:

```
@bot.command()
async def o(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    x = requests.get("https://random-data-api.com/api/phone_number/random_phone_number")
    y = x.json()
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    if x.status_code != 404:
        async with channel.typing():
            cell_phone = y["phone_number"]
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Het weer in {cell_phone}",
        color=0x00FFFF,
        timestamp=ctx.message.created_at,)
    return await channel.send(embed=embed)
```